# Redis data lost after server restart

Tags: linux, database, node.js, redis, persistence

I have configured Redis to use RDB persistence method to save data every second if single write (`save 1 1`) but still after restart I see the key value as nil.

Comment: Does it work if you run `BGSAVE` or `SAVE` before restart?

Comment: I don't want to do that and thats the reason I have set the AOF file to write every write immediately. Do you think still I need to do BGSAVE or SAVE?

Comment: No, it is not needed if `save 1 1` works. But I was wondering if the problem is with the `save 1 1` syntax or with Redis not storing properly, that's why I suggested to use `BGSAVE` and check if that one works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I found that the Redis I used to start was with the command: `redis-server &`

This command is used to start every time with new key in database, so the data stored in snapshot and AOF files was ignored.

I changed the configuration to start the redis server with the correct path to database files and started the server with following command and its working fine now: `/etc/init.d/redis_port start`